# Needing to transform proc results into SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a proc that produces a results set that is exactly what I need but I am having an issue putting that into SSRS. The issue is that the report is looking for 6 different value ranges and what plans fall into those values ranges. Using a query field wont work because there are more than one row per column. So i am confused on what to do

proc results:

[image]

Report Layout:

[image]

Comment: Share the results of the Proc and the SSRS report layout

Comment: Information is shared.

Comment: You have three "Plans" columns, which one is the report after? Also, share the results in consumable format like so - https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: It is after all three columns

Comment: So S needs to match up with S Etc etc.

Comment: create another column in the Proc for the value ranges and then in the SSRS write a condition expressiosn in each column to display data according to those that match the range

Comment: I am still having issues. I only have one dataset and need rows 2-6 for each column

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Update your question and show your sample data in the desired output format. Just mock it up in Excel of something Its difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i'm confused and yet not clear about your question but if i understand it right then you just have to add a "parent group" in your ssrs report.