# Using lookup in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have one dataset and I am trying to pick out certain rows from that dataset to populate my ssrs report. But I am having issues using the lookup function, i feel like i am using it right.

Function:

```
=LookUp(2,FieldsAccount_Range_Ind.Value,FieldsSNumberPlans.Value,”DataSet1”)
```

I need to find the second and third row of the data below

```
Account_Range_Ind   SNumberPlans    SAvgValuePlans  INumberPlans    IAvgValuePlans  YNumberPlans    YAvgValuePlans
1   1   121920.900000   1   69524.125000    0   0.000000
2   0   0.000000    1   260561.785000   0   0.000000
3   0   3017612.690000  0   0.000000    0   0.000000
```

Not sure what i am missing here, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use Lookup if you only have one dataset? Lookup is generally used to get data from other datasets. If you only have one dataset, there is almost definitely an easier way to accomplish what you are trying to do, unless there is a reason that you have to use Lookup.

Comment: No there isnt a reason why...I just googled a way to achieve that and that what was mentioned most.

Comment: any advice would be great

Comment: Usually you would want to **filter** the dataset or table rather than use the lookup function. Maybe explain why you need a certain row or what you're trying to do may help.

Comment: So as mentioned above. I have a dataset that returns 6 total rows and right now the ssrs report is only populating the first row of the query and it needs to return all 6 rows for each column

Comment: Are you displaying the data in a **table** or just a **text box**? A table should be showing all rows in the dataset (unless the data is filtered) while a text box would just show the first row from the dataset.

Comment: It is in a table, but the issue with filters is that I need to filter out 6 different row numbers and the filter is only allowing one filter to be used at a time. Anyway around that?

Comment: There are some different ways. Why do you want rows 2 and 3? Are you just looking for the ones **WHERE SNumberPlans = 0**? Add the criteria that you want to your question.

Comment: I assume this is related your your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50294035/needing-to-transform-proc-results-into-ssrs I suggest you close this question and update the other, showing your dataset result in the final output as you expect to see them.